# My footer contains 3 lists. How can this be arranged to 3 rows in non-desktop or mobile view

Tags: javascript, responsive

I have 3 lists in my footer.
In desktop version, I am seeing this -

```
    Listx Listy Listz
```

In Mobile or non-desktop, I should be able to see this -

```
     Listx
     Listy
     Listz
```

How can I adjust my CSS below in order for this 3 lists to appear like 3 separate rows?

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="footer-container">
  <div class = "container">    
    <div class = "link-div">
      <ul class="footer">
        <li >
          <a  href="www.listx.com">Listx</a>
        </li>
        <li >
          <a  href="www.listy.com">Listy</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a  href="www.listz.com">Listz</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

My Css

```
.footer-container {
    background-color:#05446c;
  text-align:left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: rgb(40,40,40)  !important;     
  bottom:0;
  padding: 7px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.link-div { 
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 50px;  
}

li a { 
  color: $color-lightest  !important; 
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

I may need a media query but after trying different adjustment on my CSS, it didn't give me the result I am expecting.

Comment: Do you want to build it with your own prepared responsive CSS or do you want to use something like 'Bootstrap' ?

Comment: We would customized responsive CSS.  Bootstrap is not necessary at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ul.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  ul.footer li {
    width: 100%;
  }    
}
```

With flexbox and media queries you could achieve that. More info about flexbox [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)